# References to deceased persons

Tags: questions

Having dealt recently with materials translated from Hebrew, I noticed that references to deceased individuals throughout the materials were made with the usage of the letters "ZL" after the person's name (apparently a transliteration of an acronym for the Hebrew expression "of blessed memory").

Seeing how that's not a common thing (as far as I know of) in US English, and the items in question were intended for common readership from what I could tell (in other words, not just Jews/Isralies familiar with that), would it not be more appropriate to change it to a form such as "the late John Smith" for example, or other alternative forms, whatever they may be, rather than preserve the exact form of the non-English source?

Comment: this is certainly POB

Answer (score 3):

You may use the **dagger** typographic symbol after the person's name.

[image]

The dagger (or obelisk) HTML code is "&#.8224 or  "&.dagger" (*the dot intentionally inserted in the codes to view them shall be removed*)

**RIP** (*Rest In Peace* from latin *requiescat in pace*) is an alternative, for example in "This university was founded by Thomas Jefferson, RIP".